# How to rotate a video and have it playable on a TV set?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, libav

I have a video which originates from a phone, and which itself plays without problems on a Thomson TV set (via USB). The details of the video is the following:

```
> avprobe 20170904_065655.mp4
avprobe version 11.3-6:11.3-1~trusty, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 13 2015 22:25:55 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20170904_065655.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-09-04 04:58:01
  Duration: 00:01:05.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17094 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17017 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-04 04:58:01
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-04 04:58:01
# avprobe output
```

The video is rotated 90 counterclockwise. Therefore, as pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83711/how-can-i-rotate-a-video), I am trying the following command line to rotate the video 90 degrees clockwise:

```
ffmpeg -i 20170904_065655.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" test.mp4
```

which, unfortunately, rotates the video by *180* degrees. Is there anything wrong with that command to rotate the video?

Anyway, I was able to rotate the video using `avidemux`, but the saved new video file (`rotated.mp4`) was not playable on the TV set ('Video format not supported'). I tried to convert the file into different formates using commands like

```
avconv -i rotated.mp4 -c:v h264 -q:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame out.avi
avconv -i rotated.mp4 -c:v mpeg1video -q:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame out.avi
avconv -i rotated.mp4 -r 25 -vb 20M  -crf 20  output.avi
avconv -i rotated.mp4  -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k  output.mp4
```

But NONE of that worked. What am I missing? Or is there a way to rotate the video on the command line without changing the actual format/encoding?

The `avprobe` of `rotated.mp4` is

```
avprobe version 11.3-6:11.3-1~trusty, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 13 2015 22:25:55 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, avi, from 'rotated.mp4':
  Duration: 00:00:30.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6728 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1080x1920 [PAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 30 fps, 30.02 tbn, 60.04 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

Using the ffmpeg from [here](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)  the `avprobe` output is the following, after I have applied the method from 'LordNeckbeard' to the `rotated.mp4`:

```
avprobe version 11.3-6:11.3-1~trusty, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 13 2015 22:25:55 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.104
  Duration: 00:00:30.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10397 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1080x1920 [PAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 8860 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: [1][0][0][0] / 0x0001, 48000 Hz, 2 channels (default)
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
# avprobe output
```

and neither the audio nor the video is supported now...

Comment: @Alex 1. Do you particularly need it to be done using avconf or ffmpeg via the command-line, or will other libre software be ok? 2. What model is the TV in question? 3. Does it matter if the format changes as long as the quality is preserved?

Comment: [This](http://www.thomsontv.eu/faq) is both somewhat helpful, and entirely useless at the same time: "This is a frequently occurring issue with files in .AVI and .DIVX format and depends on the codec used when the file is created.

If the file is unreadable, that means that its codec is not compatible with the TV."

Comment: What is the avprobe info for rotated.mp4?

Comment: @harrymc: Added the output to the question

Comment: I used the latest version, and now neither audio nor video is supported. Maybe I will look for a way to record the video from the computer screen....

Comment: The command given by LordNeckbeard shouldn't be run on `rotated.mp4`, but `input.mp4` (your original file). In your `rotated.mp4`, the audio is PCM-encoded, which is different from the original AAC. In principle you can just copy the original audio over (`-c:a copy`), and your TV should read it. Does the video play if you do `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -qscale:v 2 -an output.mp4`, i.e. with MPEG-4 codec and no audio? Or alternatively with `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -qscale:v 2 -c:a libmp3lame output.mp4`?

Comment: I did use the 64-bit 'johnvansickle' `ffmpeg` for the following two experiments. 1. Conversion as suggested by LordNeckbeard: "Video format not supported". 2. With the command you have suggested I got an expected "Audio format not supported", but the video not playing, it looks like a corrupted still image. There was NOT an "video format not supported" error this time.

Comment: @slhck: Your second command line: Pinkish still image with audio. So the same as (2.) but with audio. Maybe I am asking the impossible...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=-2:1080,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- Because the TV appears to ignore the rotate sidedata you will have to re-encode the video to rotate it. `ffmpeg` will do this automatically, so you don't have to do anything special.
- If it still doesn't work add `-profile:v baseline` for added compatibility. I recommend also trying `-profile:v main` and omitting `-profile:v`. If you can get away with it avoid `-profile:v`, next best is *main*, least optimal is *baseline*, but it doesn't really matter much for local TV playback: whatever works is best.
- The [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter will scale down the video so the height is 1080, otherwise it won't play a 1080x1920 size video.
- Using the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter will ensure a compatible pixel format. Your input is already YUV 4:2:0 planar, but this is just insurance for other input types.
- `-c:a copy` was added to stream copy (re-mux) the audio to avoid needless re-encoding. For inputs that contain audio other than AAC use `-c:a aac` instead of `-c:a copy`.
- TVs can be picky, so this may require further experimentation. To quickly test a short, 60 second segment you can add `-t 60`.
- Since the [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) tag was used I assumed you would allow it is an acceptable alternative to `avconv`. None of this may apply to `avconv` as I don't use it and I am not familiar with it. Make sure to use a recent version of `ffmpeg`. For Linux you can download a recent `ffmpeg` at https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work. The TV says, once more: "Video format not supported".

Comment: @Alex Show info for a video that does work.

Comment: Its in the beginning of the question. Or do you want to see infos from a different video?

Comment: @Alex No, sorry. I missed that it was both working and not working. Let the guessing game begin: try adding `-brand mp42`.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but still I get a "Video format not supported" error. Sound, however, works as before...

Comment: @Alex Can you verify that you used the recent version of ffmpeg from the link I provided in the answer instead of ffmpeg or avconv from the repo?

Comment: I used the latest version of `ffmpeg` and with that neither audio nor video is supported!!

Comment: So now I guess the final answer to my original question is a mix of both of the answers here ...

Comment: @Alex Does it work now after applying the commands given above, plus re-scaling?

Comment: Yes, it does work now!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the rotated video exceeds the capabilities of your TV.

The rotation changed the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1080x1920.

If your TV is 1080p (full HD) it supports 1,920x1,080, and if only
720p then 1,280x720.

In both cases, the video height is more than the maximum.
You would need a TV of 2K or 4K for such a video.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to *reduce* the resolution of the video? That would be the easier way...

Comment: @Alex To scale to 1080 pixels height, add `-filter:v "scale=-2:1080"` to the ffmpeg command (before specifying the codec etc.).

Comment: @slhck: So now I guess the final answer to my original question is a mix of both of the answers here ...

Comment: You will have to decide which answer was more essential for the final solution.

Comment: @Alex You could accept one answer and give the bounty to another, or vice-versa. There are no rules for such cases.

Comment: Alex: Do what you feel is right. Splitting acceptance & bounty is a possible solution to your dilemma.

Comment: @Alex The main problem was apparently the unsupported output size of 1080x1920 as pointed out by harrymc which I didn't consider in my original answer. I updated my answer with a new command for convenience, but whatever you decide to do is fine with us.